Geometry Area Problem
Okay so I need help solving this question. 
So I know some things which I wrote down.

Area of △ABC = area of △AFB + area of △ACF
△AFB = △ACF
△DFB = △DEF
area of △AFB - $5$ cm$^2$ - $5$ cm$^2$ = area of △AEB

I would really be thankful if someone would be able to help me solve this!

Hey! this is not hard. Just think on this: each group of triangles with same basis and same height have the same area. Can you see that BDF and DFE have the same area? They both have same basis (BD = DE) and same height (From point F to line BE)

With the same argument, DEF has area of 5, then FEB has 10. Check again and FEB has the same area of EBA = 10. Finally, the area of BFA and FCA are the same.
Area of ABC = 2 * [BFA] = 2 * (2*[BAE]) = 22(2*[BDF]) = 222*5 = 40

@luisfelipe18 FWIW, that's basically the same approach I also used, with $40$ being the same result I got.

So because I know that the area of BDF I know the whole area of EFB would be 10cm2. So because AEB has two of the same side lengths as triangle EFB it would have the same area. So triangle AFB would have an area of 20cm2. And we know that triangle AFB is the same area as ACF so the area of triangle ABC would be 40cm2?

@VioletFields yes, that is correct

A median bisects area of a triangle into two.
Go around three times, adding up areas each time.
So total $\triangle ABC $area  $= 40 cm^2, $ as shown.


Identify the triangle structure**
We are given a triangle $\triangle ABC$ and the following conditions:

$BD = DE$
$AE = EF$
$BF = FC$
The area of $\triangle DBF = 5 \, \text{cm}^2$

The equalities tell us that the triangle is divided into smaller triangles with equal areas based on the symmetry of the segments. Our goal is to calculate the area of $\triangle ABC$.
Use symmetry to find relationships**
From the diagram and conditions, we see that:

$BD = DE$, meaning $\triangle BDE$ and $\triangle DBF$ have the same area.
$AE = EF$, meaning $\triangle AEF$ and $\triangle ABE$ are congruent.
$BF = FC$, so $\triangle BFC$ is symmetric about $F$.

Thus, the equal sides divide the triangles into smaller congruent triangles, each of which contributes proportionally to the total area of $\triangle ABC$.
Relate the areas of smaller triangles**
The area of $\triangle DBF$ is given as $5 \, \text{cm}^2$. Due to symmetry:

$\triangle DBE$ has the same area as $\triangle DBF$, so $[DBE] = 5 \, \text{cm}^2$.
Similarly, $\triangle AEF$ has the same area as $\triangle DBF$, so $[AEF] = 5 \, \text{cm}^2$.
Finally, $\triangle AFC$ is congruent to $\triangle DBF$, so $[AFC] = 5 \, \text{cm}^2$.

Calculate the total area of $\triangle ABC$**
Now we sum the areas of all the triangles:

$[DBF] = 5 \, \text{cm}^2$
$[DBE] = 5 \, \text{cm}^2$
$[AEF] = 5 \, \text{cm}^2$
$[AFC] = 5 \, \text{cm}^2$

These are just part of the triangles inside $\triangle ABC$. Since $\triangle ABE$ and $\triangle BFC$ are larger triangles that include smaller triangles within them, we need to adjust the final summation for the total area.

$\triangle ABE$ is twice the area of $\triangle DBE$ and $\triangle AEF$, so $[ABE] = 10 \, \text{cm}^2$.
Similarly, $\triangle BFC$ is twice the area of $\triangle DBF$ and $\triangle AFC$, so $[BFC] = 10 \, \text{cm}^2$.

Therefore, the total area of $\triangle ABC$ is:
$\text{Total Area of } \triangle ABC = [ABE] + [BFC] = 10 + 10 + 10 + 10 = 40$
Final Answer
The correct area of $\triangle ABC$ is 40 cm².
